# Outlook Mail not sending the entire email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail, sent-items

I'm using Outlook service from the Chrome Web Browser. I'm having a Hotmail ID btw.

I don't think that my account is sending Mails in full because when I checked in the "Sent" folder only the first line was displayed. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Sent Folder screenshot]

Even upon checking the "View Message Source", the above screenshot is verified. Here's a Paste of the output from "View Message Source"

[Pastebin "View Message Source"](http://pastebin.com/7xdAXaSt)

Also, I would like to point out that this issue doesn't happen with only ONE particular email ID that I am sending to. It happened an other email ID too.
Here's the screenshot and the corresponding "Message Source" Paste.

[image: Sent Folder screenshot]

[Pastebin "View Message Source"](http://pastebin.com/6PVxua8t)

Comment: Wouldn't usually bump, but it's been a day since I've got any reply.